# How can I smooth out my model's sharp geometry after doing a boolean union on blender 2.8?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, edges, sculpting

For this model I had several separate smooth objects and then I joined them together with the boolean modifier. After that my model became sharper and jagged at the points it connected. The 2nd picture is the inside of the body looking at the arm. I've tried so many sculpting and editing tools to try to smooth it out but it doesn't work... The tools seem to have little effect even with the dyntopo tool. I've also tried to merge vertices but it said "0 vertices were removed". Subdividing and un-subdividing the arms to match the body's vertices before attaching them did not work either. Please help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems like your mesh contain duplicated vertices. Maybe try to **merge by distance** at once? Or some custom normal or attribute

Comment: I just tried to merge by distance but it said that "0 vertices were removed" unfortunately. Thanks though

Comment: Inner faces possibly. or inverted normal. Try to check both

Comment: What do you mean by inner faces? Are there not supposed to be faces on the inside/is the object not supposed to be hollow? And I don't know what you mean by inverted normals. I also changed the 2nd picture to show you the inside of the body/arm. @lemon

Comment: A bit too few elements on the pictures. Could you upload your file? Use this link if you want to do it: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: by inner faces, I mean faces that are inside the mesh, joining two opposite parts of it

Comment: ok, have the file. This is inverted normals. Enter edit mode, select all and Shift+N. But won't solve all. The base problem is the geometry is not good at all. Will be hard to fix. Should at least start from mesh parts that are approximatively at the same level of details.

Comment: That helps me a lot so I'm very grateful. This is my first question on here so I'm pretty new to how this works but don't you want to post the answer so i can confirm it and you get points? @lemon

Comment: And last question. If i continue using the model after I make it only "look better" using inverted normals but i don't change the differing levels of detail, will that have a heavy negative effect when I rig it and animate it or not really? @lemon

Comment: Well, I don't exactly know what you aim to do, but I'd say that this model won't be the best for rigging. Main causes main articulations seem to be at the boolean intersection and you can see that even not rigged it does not fit nicely.PS: by inverted normals, I meant this is partially why their is the problem, was not saying using them but make them not inverted.